# Is shear stress in flow only tangential?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

In literature, stress in fluids are decomposed of tangential (shear stress) and normal (pressure) ones.
However, the shear in the flow (not on the outer surfaces) can be also perpendicular. Am i right?
If so, why the shear stresses are only considered as tangential ones?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By Newton's 3rd law, the force per unit area exerted by the surface on the fluid is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the surface.